# Django Template is Unresponsive

Tags: javascript, django-templates, bootstrap-5

My Django Template is designed based on Bootstrap styling. However, the page is unresponsive. I think it is the issue with JavaScript, but am unable to figure it out.
I tried changing the order in which the Jquery, popper, min.js are declared. I also tried changing the browser. It's weird because it was working fine previously but something went wrong all of a sudden.

Here is the code to my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <style media="screen">
      body { padding-top: 70px; }
    </style>
    <title>Mconnect-DashBoard</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'landing:landing' %}">DashBoard</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">DB</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'hr:hr' %}"><span class="sr-only">HR</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}"><span class="sr-only">Test_DB</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-4">Test Data</h1>
      
      <hr class="my-4">
      
      <a class="lead">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Select MBDB Model</button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"><li></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:wfmain' %}">WFMAIN</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">CBSOUTQ</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">BILLS_PAYMENT</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">BILLS_PAYMENT_BBPS</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">BILLS_SERVICE</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">CLCASHREQUEST</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">IMPSMAIN</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">PORTALFTBUY</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">PORTALFTRECHARGE</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">PORTALMVISA</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">PORTALPPFACOPEN</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">PORTALTONETAG</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'test_db:test_models' %}">USERSACTIVATION</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </a>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      {% block table_block %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not use the cdn links?

Comment: The project is intended for an environment without internet access